# NodeJS Buffer is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I am trying to use Web3 to send a transaction onto the Ethereum blockchain. All parts of web3 seem to be working fine.

One step requires "Buffer" a node package, to convert a private key into some "buffered" format. I cannot for the life of me get Buffer to define itself. I know that buffer is installed in node_modules, and I have included it both in app.js and in the node controller im working on.

```
var Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;
```

Are there any other reasons Buffer would remain undefined?

index.hbs

```
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>Welcome to {{title}}</p>

<h2>Submit User Data</h2>
<form action="/addUser" method="post">
    <p>User<br><input type="text" name="userName" value="" /></p>
    <p>Address<br><input type="text" name="eth_address" value="" /></p>
    <p>Data Array<br><textarea name="data_array"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit User Data">
</form>

<h2>List User Accounts</h2>
<table width="100%" cellpadding=10 cellborder=1>
{{#if msg includeZero=true}}
    <span class='msg'>{{ msg }}</span>
{{/if}}
{{#each users}}
        <tr>
        <td><a href="/single/{{ id }}">{{userName}}</a></td>
        <td>{{eth_address}}</td>
        <td>{{data_array}}</td>
        </tr>
{{/each}}
</table>
<p>Amount (Send Limit 100)<br><input type="text" name="amount"></p>
        <p>To Address<br><input type="text" name="toAddress"></p>
        <button id="send-token" name="submit">Send Token</button>
<div class="">Acct Balance: <span id="balance"></span></div>

    <script>

        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
          web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
          // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
          web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/16aa8f4c7efc4ad3844ea4d8d1701554"));
        }

        var gasDefault = 2000000;
        var fromAddress = '0x70362Ff8842c15B1c2ECD663BD7cCED0E366f0D6';
        var fromPrivate = "censored";
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = fromAddress;

        var contractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"INITIAL_SUPPLY","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_subtractedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"decreaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_addedValue","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increaseApproval","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];

        var contractAddress = "0x302cC16165B3AE82643aC62a8b77bA48b1f03fe1";

        var daVinciContract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI);
        var daVinci = daVinciContract.at(contractAddress);
        var result = daVinci.balanceOf("0x70362Ff8842c15B1c2ECD663BD7cCED0E366f0D6",function(err, hash) {
                            if (!err)
                            $("#balance").text(hash.c[0]);
                            else
                            console.log(err);
                            });

        // toAddress = 0x1E116fD224b9185dB17DC47AC32CA30A141F67aC


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#balance").text(result); // '0x25434534534'


            // SEND TOKEN

            $("#send-token").click(function(){

                var amount = $("[name=amount]").val();
                var toAddress = $("[name=toAddress]").val();
                alert(toAddress);
                if (toAddress !=='') {


                    if (amount !=='') {
                        if (amount > 100) {
                            alert("Too much to send");
                        } else {
                            // INTITIATE TRANSACTION
                            var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress,function(err, hash) {
                            if (!err)
                            console.log(hash);
                            else
                            console.log(err);
                            });

                            // CREATE RAW TRANSACTION
                            var rawTransaction = {
                                "from": fromAddress, // Main account sending from
                                "nonce": web3.toHex(count),
                                "gasPrice": "0x04e3b29200",
                                "gasLimit": "0x7458",
                                "to": contractAddress,
                                "value": "0x0",
                                "data": daVinci.transfer.getData(toAddress, amount, {from: fromAddress})
                            };
                            var privKey = new Buffer(fromPrivate, 'hex');
                            var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);

                            tx.sign(privKey);
                            var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

                            web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
                            if (!err)
                            console.log(hash);
                            else
                            console.log(err);
                            });

                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Amount empty");
                    }
                }

            });

        });

    </script>
```

app.js

```
    var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// LOGGING
var logger = require('morgan');

// BODY POST PARSER
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Indexcontroller.js

```
    const express = require("express");
const con = require("../conn.js");

exports.indexView = (req, res) => {

    // GET USER ACCOUNT LIST


    var sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    var users = [];

    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

        var users = result;

        res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home Page',
        users: users
        });

    });






};
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you don't understand something about your code. Javascript in the `<script>` tags in your template file runs in the browser. The browser downloads the rendered HTML from your node.js server and then it parses the file and then it runs the Javascript in the `<script>` tags in the browser.

There is no `Buffer` object in the browser.

That code causing the error was apparently designed to run in node.js (not in the browser) or you are missing some environment that needs to be added to the browser to make it work or it was simply never designed to run in the browser.

You may need to move that code to your server and then use an Ajax call from your web page to your server to ask your server to run that code and return the result. Then, the code having the problem would run in node.js where it was designed to run and where there is a built-in Buffer object.

Comment: @ChaseBarnes - Read this about web3: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11991/web3-js-execution-server-vs-browser.  It is designed to run in either node.js or the browser.

Comment: @ChaseBarnes - Since the specific code in question is also referring to a private key, that probably HAS to be kept server-side anyway because it would not be private if it was allowed to be sent to the browser.